# regexp replace text betwwe

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a css file and inside it I have
`url('PTN77F-webfont.eot')` - for font name
and
`@import url("layout.css");` as import.

I need to add some text before `"PTN77F-webfont.eot"` with `preg_replace` and other text before `"layout.css"`. This are just examples, it can be any text there.
Basically I need to add some text inside the `url('abc')` and another text inside `@import url("def")`.

What I did so far is:

```
$new_file_content = preg_replace("/([^import]\s*\burl\s*\('|\")(.*)('|\"\))/i", '$1'.JURI::base().'$2$3', $new_file_content);
```

which is working fine for `url('PTN77F-webfont.eot')` but my variable is added inside the `@import url("layout.css")` also, which is no good.

Looking forward for your help.

Comment: `[^import]` does not mean "not 'import'". It means any symbol but t,i,p,m,o,r. It seems you want to exclude some location for the match. That's difficult. Also you are using `.*` greedy matches, which might match too far in. Try `?` there. (But I'm just guessing here, your explanation is too vague.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for the first one you can use the [limit parameter of preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$new_file_content = preg_replace("/([^import]\s*\burl\s*\('|\")(.*)('|\"\))/i",
'$1'.JURI::base().'$2$3', $new_file_content,1);
```